# Fitting a function to ECDF

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, polynomial, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have some ECDFs. I would like to summaries the ECDFs with functional approximations. I was thinking that a polynomial, spline, or other line fitting procedure would generate a nice parsimonious approximation, but I was curious if there were other methods more commonly used for this task. Maybe Fourier transforms or other approximation methods.

The functions I am thinking of have to be flexible. Many of the distributions I have do not come from the 'named distributions' of the exponential families. The function does have to describe the full shape, even the tails.

Comment: "Functional approximations to ECDFs" are, in so many words, *estimators of the distribution* or, at the very least, *descriptive statistics.*  As such, your question encompasses most of univariate inferential  statistics.  Could you, therefore, focus it by perhaps narrowing its scope or offering more specific criteria for solutions?

Comment: [tag:kde] is relevant because any nonparametric density estimator can be integrated to produce an instance of such a "functional approximation."

Comment: https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/density-estimation.pdf A good reference for density estimation.